# Comparing numbers give the wrong result in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

If I enter any value less than 24, it does print the "You will be old..." statement. If I enter any value greater than 24 (ONLY up to 99), it prints the "you are old" statement.

The problem is if you enter a value of 100 or greater, it prints the "You will be old before you know it." statement.

```
print ('What is your name?')
myName = input ()
print ('Hello, ' + myName)
print ('How old are you?, ' + myName)
myAge = input ()
if myAge > ('24'):
     print('You are old, ' + myName)
else:
     print('You will be old before you know it.')
```

Comment: change it to `int(myAge) > 24:` and it should work.

Comment: "*if you enter a value of 100 or greater*" -- really? What about 263?

Comment: To expand on Keiwan's comment - `'24'` is a string and not a number, so when you do comparisons to it, something like `'100'` _comes before_ `'24'` because `'1'` comes before `'2'`. This is called [_lexicographic ordering_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're testing a string value `myAge` against another string value `'24'`, as opposed to integer values.

```
if myAge > ('24'):
     print('You are old, ' + myName)
```

Should be

```
if int(myAge) > 24:
    print('You are old, {}'.format(myName))
```

In Python, you can greater-than / less-than against strings, but it doesn't work how you might think. So if you want to test the value of the integer representation of the string, use `int(the_string)`

```
>>> "2" > "1"
True
>>> "02" > "1"
False
>>> int("02") > int("1")
True
```

You may have also noticed that I changed `print('You are old, ' + myName)` to `print('You are old, {}'.format(myName))` -- You should become accustomed to this style of string formatting, as opposed to doing string concatenation with `+` -- You can read more about it in [the docs.](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) But it really doesn't have anything to do with your core problem.

Comment: What is {}'.format(myName)) doing differently than they way I had it? I am genuinely curious what the {} and .format do.

Comment: So you can think of the `{}` as a placeholder in the string for a variable, which is later supplied by `.format(variable)` For example, `"Hello, my name is {}, I am {} years old".format(myName, myAge)` would place those variables accordingly in that string. `.format` will also do type conversion for you. For example, you would have an error if you tried to do `"I am " + 24 + " years old"` because `int` and `str` types can't be added. But `"I am {} years old".format(24)` works because `format` knows to convert the type. It's also cleaner Does that help you understand it a bit better?

Comment: Much! Thank you, copying this into the Python Reference guide I am creating for myself as a cheat sheet while I learn. I am currently working through an intro and tutorial called, "Automate the Boring Stuff" and just got 'Learning Python on the Raspberry Pi'. I have been creating my own ref. guide for key commands and sample uses etc. I really am starting from nothing, but BASIC back in the 80's.

Answer (score 1):

The string `'100'` is indeed less than the string `'24'`, because `'1'` is "alphabetically" smaller than `'2'`. You need to compare *numbers*.

```
my_age = int(input())
if my_age > 24:
```

Comment: I noticed how you used an underscore between my_age, rather than using 'myAge', I have seen it done both ways, is 'myAge' not the norm? or acceptable?

Comment: PEP8 (the de facto style guide for Python) recommends such "snake case" for identifiers. Camel case is reserved for user-defined class names, and even then should always begin with a capital letter as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
print ('What is your name?')
myName = input ()
print ('Hello, ' + myName)
print ('How old are you?, ' + myName)
myAge = input ()
if int(myAge) > 24:
     print('You are old, ' + myName)
else:
     print('You will be old before you know it.')
```

Just a small thing about your code. You should convert the input from `myAge` to an integer (`int`) *(number)* and then compare that number to the number 24.;

Also, you should usually not add strings together as it is consider *non-pythonic* and it slow. Try something like `print ('Hello, %s' % myName)` instead of `print ('Hello, ' + myName)`.

[Python Strings Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Use `int(myAge)`. I always use `raw_input` and also, you dont have to print your questions. Instead put the question in with your raw_inputs like so:

```
myName = raw_input("Whats your name?")
print ('Hello, ' + myName)
myAge = raw_input('How old are you?, ' + myName)
if int(myAge) > ('24'):
    print('You are old, ' + myName)
else:
    print('You will be old before you know it.')
```