# Script to find which number is larger keeps giving incorrect answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

This script is supposed to ask for two numbers and output which number is larger, but keeps giving incorrect answers, such as 54>3514 and so on.

```
def numberThingy():
num1=input("Enter first number: ").strip()
num2=input("Enter second number: ").strip()

if num1>num2:
    print("The first number is larger.")
elif num1<num2:
    print("The second number is larger.")
else:
    print("The numbers are equal.")

while True:
    numberThingy()
```

Comment: Classic: you're comparing strings instead of numbers. `54 < 1234` but `'54' > '1234'` alphanumerically. You need to convert the string to a number, i.e. pass it through `int()` or `float()`.

Comment: Thanks, I just started using python a few days ago, so I'm quite bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing numbers give the wrong result in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981237/comparing-numbers-give-the-wrong-result-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast int to the input. When input is given, it is a string by default. You also don't need the .strip() in this situation.

```
def numberThingy():
    num1=int(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2=int(input("Enter second number: "))
    if num1>num2:
    print("The first number is larger.")
    elif num1<num2:
        print("The second number is larger.")
    else:
        print("The numbers are equal.")

while True: numberThingy()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm very new at this

Comment: You're correct, but please don't answer duplicate questions (always start by doing a quick search for existing answers before spending the time to write the answer)

Comment: That's usually the plan but I don't have enough rep to ask for clarification and such.