# 3 is bigger than 10 according to python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm new to python and I wrote a simple script to check if numbers given by user are eual or not.
And if i put first number as 3 and second number as 10 this is happening:
[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfVzy.png)

This is the code:

```
print("exercise. 1")
a = input("Enter first number: ")
b = input("Enter second number: ")

if a == b:
    print("numbers are qual")
elif a > b:
    print(a, " is bigger")
else:
    print(b, " is bigger")
```

Comment: input returns `str`. You need to convert to `int` in order to compare numeric value

Comment: `input` returns you a string and `'3'` is bigger than `'10'` because strings are compared lexicographically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing numbers give the wrong result in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981237/comparing-numbers-give-the-wrong-result-in-python)

Comment: Also see [How to parse user input as a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262772/how-to-parse-user-input-as-a-number) to get input as number

Comment: did you check the link provided?

Comment: Okay i checked link and it works. Thank You for help!